# Android: is it possible to go to a different activity once you log into website via WebView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I want to create a native Android application based on my existing website.

Due to extreme time constraints and the fact that we don't have an API server set up, I think it'd be fastest to just embed the website as a WebView in my mobile app.

So, here's what I had in mind for the mobile app:

The website has a login page.

I want that login page to be the the first screen that comes up when you enter the mobile app.

Once you hit the "sign in" button on the WebView login page and the login credentials are valid, I want it to take you to a new activity (I have no clue if this is possible since you have to detect the button click on the webview and then determine whether the credentials are valid).

Apologies, in case it's not painfully obvious, I'm not really a mobile developer. How would you guys go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Does that next activity still contains WebView inside and just want display different buttons through another activity?

If that is the case, you can use this code

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    // Override URL

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if(url.equals("http://Url displayed after successfull log-in"))
        {                       
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), APImages.class);
            startActivity(i);                   
            return true;
        }           
        return false;
    }

});
```

But if the case is after you logged - in through web, user will be redirected to Activity and will display data from WebView, it is impossible considering that you have no API to communicate with your Web App.